# "is not a function" error when calling a method from basic pageobject page in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, pageobjects, webdriver-io

I've been using page object pattern and WebdriverIO and tried to declare a selector that will be inherited in child pages. I tried both this

```
function Page() {
    this.loader = function() {
        return $("div[class*='loading'] svg");
    }
}
```

and this

```
Page.prototype.loader = function() {
    return $("div[class*='loading'] svg");
}
```

And when I call this function from child pages, e.g

```
checkoutPage.loader.waitForVisible(5000, true);
```

I get "checkoutPage.loader.waitForVisible" is not a function" error. How can I declare getter for basic page so it could be called from any child?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `checkoutPage.loader().waitForVisible()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `checkoutPage.loader.waitForVisible(5000, true)` You are actually returning the entire `loader` function not the element.

Change it to `checkoutPage.loader().waitForVisible(5000, true);` and your first example should work just fine.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Any explanations why it worked without parentheses if I override loader in checkoutPage like this? I don't want to change test itself if I have to override loader in child page.

`var checkoutPage = Object.create(page, {
    loader: {get: function() {return $("div[class*='loading'] svg");}}
})
module.exports = checkoutPage;`

Comment: Yeah, because when you use a `getter` you are binding the property to a function that gets called when you reference that property. So, when you use `get` the function is actually executing when you call `checkoutPage.loader` and returning your element. It doesn't work the same as the code you posted in your question. You can read more about it here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get